# Where should location be captured

Tags: android, locationmanager

As many of you may know, the (default?) way to request location updates is by calling this code:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();  
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(  
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
```

Now, assume you must receive location updates or very long periods of time (even if the app is in background). This implies that:

1. one cannot 'tie' the LocationListener to an activity because as soon as the activity is destroyed, the locations will no longer be captured.
2. The location manager cannot be tied to a IntentService, because it will execute and finish right away.

**My question:** Where is the best place to capture location updates for long periods of time, even when you app is in the background?

Comment: use a service, the service will run until the user stops it

Comment: @JRowan how do you suggest implementing this Service?
Given that the locations are sent asynchronously, would you just 
do a `while(true)`?

Comment: i put as answer a service that will run and get location updates even when the app is closed, the user can turn service on and off

Answer (score 0):

service for location updates continuously even when app is closed

```
public class gpsservice extends Service{

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    MyLocationListener locationListenerp;
    public gpsservice() {


    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListenerp = new MyLocationListener();  
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(  
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListenerp);




    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerp);



    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "location Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }

     public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I was here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {            
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }
}
```